# The API isnt getting access token

Tags: php, curl, authorization

This is the error am getting in my curl PHP

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 WWW-Authenticate: Bearer WWW-Authenticate: Bearer X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 10:57:54 GMT Content-Length: 61 {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}";

The API isn't receiving an access token, I think its lacking authorization. pls help me with this below authorization code to add in my code properly, am a little bit confused where to add it.

below is the authorisation code

```
curl_setopt($handle1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token));
```

//the code I have written

```
    <?php
    $access_token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $request_headers = array();
    $request_headers[] = 'Bearer: ' . $access_token;
    //$request_headers[]='Content-Length:150';
    $handle1 = curl_init();
    $api_url = 'API';


    curl_setopt_array(
        $handle1,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $api_url,
            CURLOPT_POST => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $request_headers,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => -1,
        )
    );

    $data = curl_exec($handle1);
    echo serialize($data);
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you so much it's working now..thank you so much for the help

Comment: I switch my comment to an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request_headers[] = 'Bearer: ' . $access_token;`

it seems like a typo -> `$request_headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token;`